# How instantiation is happening in this code of java?

Tags: java

my code is:-

```
class Building{}

class Barn extends Building{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Building build1 = new Building();
        Barn bar1 = new Barn();
        Barn bar2 = (Barn)build1;
        Object obj1 = (Object)build1;
        String str1 = (String)build1;    //also an error over here
        Building build2 = (Building)bar1;
    }
}
```

I am new to Java. so please can anyone explain me how the instantiation is being carried out here, like how the access is been given to each of the objects.

Also there is an error in the code please help me to rectify it too.

Comment: I hope  "Barn extends building" is typo, it should be  Barn extends Building

Comment: String and Building are no way related (no inheritance), so you will get compile time error at line  String str1 = (String)build1;. All other lines compile because they are related.

Comment: The more interesting to learn, it to work with Eclipse, and with debugger step by step follow the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this `Barn bar2 = (Barn)build1;`

The part after the equal<sup>((Barn)build1)</sup> means that you are typecasting **build1**  **from** type Building **to** the type **Barn** and passing it's value to bar2.

You could do that because any Barn **is** a Building, as you extended in class definition <sup>(Barn extends Building)</sup>. You can also typecast any class type to Object class, because in Java, all classes extends from Object, aka everything is a Object.

You are having that error when trying to cast it as String because Building has no conection with String class. Got it?

Comment: but please tell me how the privileges vary in each of the objects declared above...like which object can have access to which all members of the classes(if defined)...i hope u got my question?

Comment: You can only instantiate using `new` operator, at first. You did that twice in your code, the other cases are value assignment while casting value type.
That topic ( type casting) should be learned after you have understood the core principles of Java. You should first understand the basics of Object Oriented programming. I can recommend you to read **Head First Java** - in a few days you will have a big leap of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast `Building` as a type of `String`.  There's no relation between the two classes (inheritance, interface, etc).

It's certainly the case that a `Building` is an `Object`, but you'd lose information about your `Building` object by casting it to `Object`.

Instantiating a variable is right-to-left associative; you create a new instance of each object, and assign it to a variable.  If you're doing a cast, then it's important to ensure that the type you're casting to relates to the type you're getting (i.e. casting an `Object` as an `Integer` - which may or may not work, depending on if what you get back could be reasonably cast as an `Integer`).

Comment: but please tell me how the privileges vary in each of the objects declared above...like which object can have access to which all members of the classes(if defined)...i hope u got my question?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Building b = (Building) (new Barn());
```

will have access to all of Building's members and fields, disregarding the added Barn fields (it's called downcasting);

```
  Barn b = (Barn) (new Building());
```

will result in null-pointers when accessing barn-specific members or will leave them uninitialized... i kinda forgot what happens when you up-cast as it makes little sense to cast an Animal to a Cat unless you're expecting a Cat ;)

without specific methods or a debugger, you won't be able to notice the difference. I don't see a use-case in your code, only casting.

Comment: Except `Barn b = (Barn) (new Building());` will generate a `ClassCastException`, because you can't actually cast a `Building` to a `Barn` (not all buildings will be barns, after all).